# Design class to handle calls for support functions

Tags: c#, .net

For the following problem statement, I design following classes.  Can you please tell me if this is the correct implementation or if there can be a better one?

Let's say there is call center with three levels of employees: fresher, technical lead (TL), product manager (PM). There can be multiple employees, but only one TL or PM. An incoming telephone call must be allocated to a fresher who is free. If a fresher can’t handle the call, he or she must escalate the call to technical lead. If the TL is not free or not able to handle it, then the call should be escalated to PM. Design the classes and data structures for this problem.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestNS
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsFree { get; set; }
        public Employee Manager { get; set; }
    }

    public class Call
    {
        public Employee AllocatedTo { get; set; }

        public bool HandleCall()
        {
            AllocatedTo.IsFree = false;
            bool isHandled = false;

            // Write custom logic to handle the call & set the value of isHandled

            if (isHandled)
            {
                AllocatedTo.IsFree = true;
            }

            return isHandled;
        }

        public void Escalate()
        {
            AllocatedTo = AllocatedTo.Manager;
            HandleCall();
        }
    }

    public class CallManager
    {
        List<Employee> fresherList = new List<Employee>();
        public void CreateEmployeeList()
        {
            Employee PM = new Employee() { Name = "PM1", IsFree = true };

            Employee TL = new Employee() { Name = "TL1", IsFree = true };
            TL.Manager = PM;

            fresherList = new List<Employee>();
            fresherList.Add(new Employee() { Name = "F1", Manager = TL, IsFree = true });
            fresherList.Add(new Employee() { Name = "F2", Manager = TL, IsFree = true });
            fresherList.Add(new Employee() { Name = "F3", Manager = TL, IsFree = true });
            fresherList.Add(new Employee() { Name = "F4", Manager = TL, IsFree = true });
            fresherList.Add(new Employee() { Name = "F5", Manager = TL, IsFree = true });
            fresherList.Add(new Employee() { Name = "F6", Manager = TL, IsFree = true });
        }

        private Employee FindFreeEmployee()
        {
            Employee e = null;
            foreach (Employee emp in fresherList)
            {
                if (emp.IsFree)
                {
                    e = emp;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return e;
        }

        public void ReceiveAndAllocateCall(Call call1)
        {
            call1.AllocatedTo = FindFreeEmployee();
            call1.HandleCall();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your scenario can perfectly take advantage of [Chain Of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) Design Pattern. Have a look at it and see if its perfect for you problem. You can find many examples of implementation in .NET.

Comment: I think "CallManager` is a very bad name, it does not describe what the class does ("manage" can mean almost anything). There is a method named "..AllocateCall", this is closer to the true purpose of the class. Perhaps `CallAllocator` or `CallRouter` would be better names.

Answer (score 2):

1. I like the `Employee` class with the built-in `Manager` chain.
2. I think `Call` class should be "dumb" like the `Employee`. The methods seem like call processing - what the `CallManager` should be doing.
3. Id say part of the "call handing process" is in the `CallManager` and part of it is in `Call` class. Broken apart like this it's hard to discern/follow the flow of a call-handling.
4. Should you implement queues? A queue of `Call`s to model lots of calls coming in before they can get allocated.
5. The code has allocation and "isFree" as 2 separate things. This suggests to me that we could have a `Employee.CallQueue` for allocated calls, then set `IsFree = false` when he picks up the phone.
6. Also an `Employee.CallQueue` of assigned calls. The code suggests that allocation and handling are 2 separate things
7. In `ReceiveAndAllocateCall.FindFreeEmployee()` could return `null` so we need code to handle that. Maybe that when the call goes into a waiting queue.

---

```
public class CallManager {
     . . .

    // call processing
    call1.AllocatedTo = FindFreeEmployee();

    // what to do if AllocatedTo is null?

    call1.AllocatedTo.IsFree = false;
    call1.IsHandled = false; 

    // I see `IsHandled` as a `Call` property. It will persist if we 
    // pass it to the manager. As is, `IsHandled` disappears when `HandleCall()` ends and we don't know if the call is handled anymore.

    while (! call1.IsHandled) {
     // Write custom logic to handle the call & set the value of isHandled
     if (! call1.isHandled) {
         if (call1.AllocatedTo.Manager != null) { call1.AllocateTo = AllocateTo.Manager
         }else{ break;}
      }
    } // while

    // if IsHandled == false still, what to do? Hang up and send them a lollypop I guess.
```

- The 1st line, calling `FindFreeEmployee()` might best be done outside of, or somewhere else in `CallManager` Imagine a complex process for deciding how to pair calls to employees. Then pass that pair into `CallManager`, and all call manager does is process the call. - Separation of Responsibilities.